# Bizarre glitch in MATLAB vector assignment

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, while-loop, variable-assignment

I have a section of code in which I'm picking out the x values spaced at ds within a given threshold d/2. This might not be the most efficient way to do it, but it besides the occasional bug I'm bringing up here it works fine and I'd like to leave the methodology as is. However, MATLAB seems to chop off the upper endpoint off the vector created by this code. My guess is that it's having some sort of rounding error and doesn't hit the upper limit right. It works just fine with different (but same order of magnitude) values of d and ds.

```
d=250e-9;
ds=1e-9;
xlim=0;

while xlim < ((d/2)-ds)
    xlim = xlim + ds;
end;

disp(xlim);
```

xlim is returned as 1.25e-7. Then,

```
xrel = -xlim:ds:xlim
```

This displays xrel, which starts at -1.25e-7 and ends at 1.24e-7. Incidentally, there are exactly 250 values (later in my code I count on this being an odd value). Any ideas on a work around? Thanks!

Comment: It's not really a 'rounding error', floating point addition just doesn't guarantee correctness when dealing with values that small. My answer below should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you type: 
    format long

before doing this, you will see that xlim is not exactly 1.25e-7 after your procedure. This is a bad way of doing this, do the following instead:

```
xrel = -d/2:ds:d/2
```

This will give you the 251-length vector with values from -1.25e-7 to 1.25e-7 that you want.

Comment: Alternatively, consider using the linspace function if you know exactly how many points you want and you have the upper and lower bounds.